# simplest possible C program to print UUID of /dev/sda1

Tags: c, uuid

I need to write a simple program in C which will print the `UUID` of `/dev/sda1`. It does not have take any parameters (`/dev/sda1` can be hardcoded)

I have no idea how this can be done in C, but hopefully this could be done in few lines of code.

Could somebody please point me to the right direction, or perhaps sketch some code ?

Comment: Did you want to post a challenge on [codegolf.SE]?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about just googling "UUID sda1"? First link you get is to system util that can get it to you. Second step - look up source code of that util (which happens to be in C).

Comment: It's not even clear what you're asking. Are you talking about parsing a particular file system that has a UUID? Maybe parsing the GPT table? Something else?

Comment: @Andrey - I have found system utilities that do that. But I need a C program which I can adjust for my purpose.

Comment: @MartinVegter system utility **is** a C program with open source.

Comment: @Andrew Medico - what is not clear? I have a partition `/dev/sda1` which has a UUID. How can I print this UUID in a C program.

Comment: @Andrey - but I am specifically looking for a "hello world" type program, not a full blown application.

Comment: @MartinVegter you want hello world type program dealing with OS internals? Did you try to actually look up source code of said utilities? They are written very clearly and not hard to read. Seriously, maybe put some effort?

Comment: @MartinVegter What result shall the algorithm produce for file systems without a UUID or for those where the identification number has a different format?

Comment: @MartinVegter I listed two distinct possibilities, and AndreyT pointed out a third (the Linux-specific block device ID concept). Are you asking about one of these things (and if so, **which**) or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/blkid.c line 211

```
    /* Get the uuid, label, type */
    iter = blkid_tag_iterate_begin(dev);
    while (blkid_tag_next(iter, &type, &value) == 0) {
        if (!strcmp(type, "UUID"))
            uuid = value;
    }
    blkid_tag_iterate_end(iter);
```